# ZipCode data for historical dates

Tags: entity

I am trying to get historical values of certain properties of a ZIPCode entity.

To get the current data I write:

`EntityValue[Entity["ZIPCode","60007"],"AverageHouseValue"]`

How can I get historical data?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing the knowledge base doesn't have historical data for this property. Normally [`Dated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dated.html) would work, but it doesn't in this case. Also compare the qualifiers for the following properties. One has historical data and one doesn't seem to: `EntityValue[EntityProperty["Country", "Population"], "Qualifiers"]` and `EntityValue[EntityProperty["ZIPCode", "AverageHouseValue"], "Qualifiers"]`.